# Using Chrome scraper to extract data from JavaScript site

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I need to extract data from this site:
http://www.guidetorulingtheworld.ca/Path/apps/cato/sortfims.aspx?FirmRegionNumber=12&locality=A

I need to touch base with these firms as they are potential employers and I am limited to working for them to obtain my designation. Altogether there another 10 or so similar pages on this site that have listed firms that I'll need to apply this method to (about 300 firms).

I tried using a scraper on chrome and data tool on explorer but neither work fully with this site. Actually explorer's data tool didn't respond in any way.

The company contact information is embedded in the JavaScript for each company and displayed on click. The scraper tool extracts the URL for the JavaScript but not the resulting data. Is there an extension or Excel VBA script I can use, and would automatically extract the data in the JavaScript?

Comment: I suggest that you start by publishing exactly what you've tried so far. This way others can point what you can improve.

Comment: Thanks @Noich: I installed scraper, highlighted part of the list of firms, right clicked and selected 'scrap similar', the full list loaded in scraper, clicked on preset and selected link, and then I clicked export to google. I don't know how to use Xpath or jQuery so no changes, all other settings left as default. the entire page extracted, with titles and related links for everything on the page.

Comment: Titles with javascripts as urls showed their java path, and titles with html urls showed their html path. The contact information that is generated by clicking on the javascrip url of each firm was not extracted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Java Programmer use HTML Unit - although it is unit testing library it's good for web scraping. It's headless browser that fully supports JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Biera. I am not a programmer, I would say I am an intermediate to advanced end user, to be very generous. Regardless I'm going to install it and see if I can use it.